# Как с помощью JSON получить нужные элементы по заданным парам?

Tags: python, json

Дан API с таким кодом, часть его:

```
[ ....
 {"A":"Стол","C":"Дерево","D":"Складной","H":"60см", "S":"40см"},
 {"A":"Стул","C":"Дерево","D":"Складной","H":"20см", "S":"20см"},
 {"A":"Стол","C":"ДСП","D":"Складной","H":"60см", "S":"40см"},
 ....
 ]
```

Как через JSON можно получить у API все словари, у которых обязательно присутствуют эти пары: `"A":"Стол","C":"Дерево", "S":"40см"`?

То есть, по данному примеру получить на выходе:

```
{"A":"Стол","C":"Дерево","D":"Складной","H":"60см", "S":"40см"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так на чистом python это можно сделать

```
filter_dict = {"A": "Стол", "C": "Дерево", "S": "40см"}
items = filter_dict.items()
l = [
   {"A": "Стол", "C": "Дерево", "D": "Складной", "H": "60см", "S": "40см"},
   {"A": "Стул", "C": "Дерево", "D": "Складной", "H": "20см", "S": "20см"},
   {"A": "Стол", "C": "ДСП", "D": "Складной", "H": "60см", "S": "40см"},
]
result = [x for x in l if all(k in x and x[k] == v for k,v in items)]
```

В итоге в result -> список словарей:

```
[{'A': 'Стол', 'C': 'Дерево', 'D': 'Складной', 'H': '60см', 'S': '40см'}]
```

**Дополнение [альтернативная запись]:**

```
result = []
for x in l:
  for k, v in items:
     if k not in x or x[k] != v:
        break
  else:
     result.append(x)
```

***Пояснение**

```
k in x and x[k] == v
```

делают именно так, а не x.get(k) == v, потому что v может быть само себе None и тогда вернется True, чего мы в данном случае явно не хотим

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, вот эту строчку, не пойму как вообще она работает? `result = [x for x in l if all(x[k] == v for k,v in items if k in x)]`

Comment: @ChikChirik, обновил ответ возможно так будет понятней, но по сути - тоже самое all делает под "Капотом"

Comment: `[{'A': 'Стол', 'C': 'ДСП', 'D': 'Складной', 'H': '60см', 'S': '40см'}]` у меня на выходе получается

Comment: @ChikChirik, проверяю у себя - все ок.  filter_dict точно указан верно?

Comment: да, все перепроверил, итоговый код: `filter_dict = {"A": "Стол", "C": "Дерево", "S": "40см"}
items = filter_dict.items()
l = [
   {"A": "Стол", "C": "Дерево", "D": "Складной", "H": "60см", "S": "40см"},
   {"A": "Стул", "C": "Дерево", "D": "Складной", "H": "20см", "S": "20см"},
   {"A": "Стол", "C": "ДСП", "D": "Складной", "H": "60см", "S": "40см"},
] 
result = []
for x in l:
  for k, v in items:
     if k in x and x[k] == v:
        break
  else:
     result.append(x)`

Comment: @ChikChirik, этот код не верен, в альтернативной запись строка условия  отличается - "if k not in x or x[k] != v"

Comment: `result = []
for x in l:
    for k, v in items:
        if k not in x or x[k] != v:
            break
        else:
            result.append(x)
            print(result)`   на выходе `[{'A': 'Стол', 'C': 'Дерево', 'D': 'Складной', 'H': '60см', 'S': '40см'}]
[{'A': 'Стол', 'C': 'Дерево', 'D': 'Складной', 'H': '60см', 'S': '40см'}, {'A': 'Стол', 'C': 'Дерево', 'D': 'Складной', 'H': '60см', 'S': '40см'}]
[{'A': 'Стол', 'C': 'Дерево', 'D': 'Складной', 'H': '60см', 'S': '40см'}, {'A': 'Стол', 'C': 'Дерево', 'D': 'Складной', 'H': '60см', 'S': '40см'}, {'A': 'Стол', 'C': 'ДС.....`

Comment: @ChikChirik, если точно там стоит? (как в моем ответе), без отступов этого не понять

Comment: if под последним for, else тоже под for, все как у вас в пункте  Дополнение [альтернативная запись]

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102332/discussion-between-chikchirik-and-basalex).

Comment: отправил в чат скрин, чтоб понятнее было

Answer (score 3):

Пример с использованием модуля Pandas:

исходные данные:

```
In [22]: import pandas as pd   #  pip install pandas

In [23]: data
Out[23]:
[{'A': 'Стол', 'C': 'Дерево', 'D': 'Складной', 'H': '60см', 'S': '40см'},
 {'A': 'Стул', 'C': 'Дерево', 'D': 'Складной', 'H': '20см', 'S': '20см'},
 {'A': 'Стол', 'C': 'ДСП', 'D': 'Складной', 'H': '60см', 'S': '40см'}]
```

создаем Pandas DataFrame из списка словарей:

```
In [24]: df = pd.DataFrame(d)

In [25]: df
Out[25]:
      A       C         D     H     S
0  Стол  Дерево  Складной  60см  40см
1  Стул  Дерево  Складной  20см  20см
2  Стол     ДСП  Складной  60см  40см
```

задаем условия поиска:

```
In [26]: search_cond = {"A":"Стол","C":"Дерево","D":"Складной","H":"60см", "S":"40см"}

In [27]: qry = ' and '.join([(f"{k} == '{v}'") for k,v in search_cond.items()])
```

получилась строка поиска:

```
In [28]: qry
Out[28]: "A == 'Стол' and C == 'Дерево' and D == 'Складной' and H == '60см' and S == '40см'"
```

фильтруем DataFrame:

```
In [29]: res_df = df.query(qry)
```

результат:

```
In [30]: res_df
Out[30]:
      A       C         D     H     S
0  Стол  Дерево  Складной  60см  40см
```

результат в виде словаря:

```
In [31]: res = df.query(qry).to_dict("records")

In [32]: res
Out[32]: [{'A': 'Стол', 'C': 'Дерево', 'D': 'Складной', 'H': '60см', 'S': '40см'}]
```